# 401 Unauthorised in wso2 serrvice provider inittialisation

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to hit the initiliase service provider api /services/IdentityApplicationManagementService  using request body:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <xsd:createApplication>
                                <xsd:serviceProvider>
                                    <xsd1:applicationName>$1</xsd1:applicationName>
                                </xsd:serviceProvider>
                            </xsd:createApplication>
                        </soapenv:Body>`enter code here`
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

But its giving 401 Unauthorized error. I am doing this in wso2 integration studio .

Answer (score 0):

This request fails since it is an unauthorised request. You need to add basic authorisation to the request. Refer to the blog post [1] on invoking admin services.

[1]-https://medium.com/@naduni_pamudika/calling-wso2-admin-services-78afa7dd4c44

Comment: okay, got it. I enabled the wso2 admin services and tried the https://localhost:9443/services/IdentityApplicationManagementService?wsdlalso. There it is coming but when sending a req through postman it says 401 again. Also, Any idea on how to add authorization to the request in wso2 enterprise integrator? I am new to wso2 so having these doubts. Thanks in advance!